# Zsh - stop first line output being in bold

Tags: git, zsh

Using Zsh 5.6.2.... not oh my zsh, just the normal one.

Anyone know how to stop this behavior where the first line is in bold with git branch? For instance, in the picture `S49/MSP-3638/ee-participating-clients` is in bold. Or maybe it's just a brighter white. Ether way, I would like it to be the same as the rest of the branches listed.

[image]

Comment: `git branch` is colorizing branches. You can disable all colorization with the `--no-color` option, or just for remote branches by setting `color.branch.remote = never` in your configuration file.

Comment: It doesn't like `never`. How else could I do this just for branch.remove?

Comment: Hm. `git help config` suggests `false` and `never` are synonyms in this context; try `false`? (Also: is `color.branch.remote` itself a valid variable, or does it have to be `branch.remote` in a `[color]` section?)

Comment: Another thought: how are you making the command you type (i.e., `git branch`) bright white? Are you setting the foreground color at the end of your prompt, or using `zle_highlight`? (The former could be affecting the command output.)

Comment: No, not using `zle_highlight`. That white is from urxvt-terminal and .Xdefaults